# Forbidden You don't have permission to access - Magento 2.2.9

Tags: magento2, theme, upgrade

When I'm trying to change my theme with the luma theme from backend on Magento 2.2.9 after upgrade from Magento 2.2.6, I'm getting following error.[image]

Please help

Comment: try with sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

Answer (score 0):

**This is Permission Error, Try to Use Sudo Command as**

For Ex: sudo php bin/magento s:up && sudo php bin/magento s:d:c && sudo php bin/magento s:s:d -f && sudo php bin/magento c:c && sudo php bin/magento c:f

Or You have Permission Error

**Please use following Command for Permission as**

For Ex: sudo chmod -R 777 var/ pub/ generated/